# Tempo TLS issue

Tags: grafana, tls1.2, otel, tempo, grafana-tempo

i have configured below TLS in tempo configuration, My application is displaying below error for tempo otlp endpoint. In Grafana i am able to add data source using https://x.x.x.x:3200  URL. But application is having issue sending traces to the collector endpoint.

```
2024-03-13T04:17:47,743 ERROR [grpc-default-executor-2] i.o.e.o.trace.OtlpGrpcSpanExporter - Failed to export spans. Server is UNAVAILABLE. Make sure your collector is running and reachable from this network. Full error message:UNAVAILABLE
```

My Tempo configuration

```
stream_over_http_enabled: true
server:
  http_listen_port: 3200
  log_level: info
  tls_cipher_suites: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
  tls_min_version: VersionTLS12
  grpc_tls_config:
        cert_file: /etc/tempo/example.crt
        key_file: /etc/tempo/example.key
        client_auth_type: VerifyClientCertIfGiven
        client_ca_file: /etc/tempo/ca.crt
  http_tls_config:
        cert_file: /etc/tempo/example.crt
        key_file: /etc/tempo/example.key
        client_auth_type: VerifyClientCertIfGiven
        client_ca_file: /etc/tempo/ca.crt

querier:
  frontend_worker:
    grpc_client_config:
       tls_enabled: true
       tls_cert_path: /etc/tempo/example.crt
       tls_key_path:  /etc/tempo/example.key
       tls_ca_path: /etc/tempo/ca.crt
       tls_insecure_skip_verify: true
       tls_cipher_suites: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       tls_min_version: VersionTLS12


query_frontend:

  search:
    duration_slo: 5s
    throughput_bytes_slo: 1.073741824e+09
  trace_by_id:
    duration_slo: 5s

metrics_generator_client:
 grpc_client_config:
   tls_enabled: true
   tls_cert_path: /etc/tempo/example.crt
   tls_key_path:  /etc/tempo/example.key
   tls_ca_path: /etc/tempo/ca.crt
   tls_insecure_skip_verify: true
   tls_cipher_suites: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
   tls_min_version: VersionTLS12

ingester_client:
   grpc_client_config:
     tls_enabled: true
     tls_cert_path: /etc/tempo/example.crt
     tls_key_path:  /etc/tempo/example.key
     tls_ca_path: /etc/tempo/ca.crt
     tls_insecure_skip_verify: true
     tls_cipher_suites: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     tls_min_version: VersionTLS12



distributor:
  receivers:                           # this configuration will listen on all ports and protocols that tempo is capable of.
    jaeger:                            # the receives all come from the OpenTelemetry collector.  more configuration information can
      protocols:                       # be found there: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/receiver
        thrift_http:                   #
        grpc:                          # for a production deployment you should only enable the receivers you need!
        thrift_binary:
        thrift_compact:
    zipkin:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        http:
             tls:
                 ca_file: /etc/tempo/ca.crt
                 cert_file: /etc/tempo/example.crt
                 key_file:  /etc/tempo/example.key



        grpc:
             tls:
                 ca_file: /etc/tempo/ca.crt
                 cert_file: /etc/tempo/example.crt
                 key_file:  /etc/tempo/example.key

    opencensus:

ingester:
  max_block_duration: 5m               # cut the headblock when this much time passes. this is being set for demo purposes and should probably be left alone normally

compactor:
  compaction:
    block_retention: 1h                # overall Tempo trace retention. set for demo purposes

metrics_generator:
  registry:
    external_labels:
      source: tempo
      cluster: docker-compose
  storage:
    path: /tmp/tempo/generator/wal
    remote_write:
      - url: http://192.168.1.90:9090/api/v1/write
        send_exemplars: true

memberlist:
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_cert_path: /etc/tempo/example.crt
    tls_key_path: /etc/tempo/example.key
    tls_ca_path: /etc/tempo/ca.crt
    tls_insecure_skip_verify: true


storage:
  trace:
    backend: local                     # backend configuration to use
    wal:
      path: /tmp/tempo/wal             # where to store the the wal locally
    local:
      path: /tmp/tempo/blocks

overrides:
  defaults:
    metrics_generator:
      processors: [service-graphs, span-metrics] # enables metrics generator
```

I have enabled TLS in tempo , i am expecting application to send traces to an https:// endpoint without any issue.